# PHP script to sit and wait to capture a Webhook

Tags: php, webhooks

I am wanting to capture a Webhook in PHP. I dont know when the webhook will come through so I have to keep the site actively looping until it does. The response comes through in a JSON array, so I want to display this to see if it works if possible.

Could someone please send through some sample PHP to do this?

I tried it like this and I kept getting errors after 30 seconds

```
<?php
$webhookContent = "";

do {
$webhook = fopen('php://input' , 'rb');
while (!feof($webhook)) {
    $webhookContent .= fread($webhook, 4096);
}
fclose($webhook);

error_log($webhookContent);

} while ($webhookContent == "");

echo $webhook;
?>
```

The error I got was

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/passames/public_html/hook/hook.php on line 11

I also tried to echo $webhookcontent with no luck.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: To solve that error take a look at this http://php.net/manual/es/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: if you're executing a PHP script that has to loop indefinitely, don't do it through your web server but do it from the command line. there's no timeout default for the CLI

Comment: On a side note, PHP isn't the ideal language for processes like this - if you can you should look at using node.js instead which is

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that you really need to loop infinitely. In all likelihood, you can just process the input whenever a request comes in, just like any other page. See, for example, the [Stripe webhooks documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks).

Comment: Hi. Thanks the error is solved. Any idea with the rest please? The data is not being displayed.

Comment: Hey Robbie, could you elaborate please? It looks like you were about to direct me somewhere. Also Ed, sorry I am new to this game, and not sure what you mean. I have a URL that is sending me a JSON script each time something is scanned. If I point it to a URL that is not running what will happen? Does it initiate the web page automatically?

Comment: @RenegadeRob Yes, requesting the URL will trigger execution of the script, as long as it's a working URL. It sounds like you need to read an introductory tutorial in how PHP works. Also, Robbie's comments are only relevant if you really need to have an infinite loop. As I said, it would be extremely unusual if you needed that. What you have described sounds like a very normal webhook scenario, in which you do not need an infinite loop.

Comment: Hi Ed. Thanks. Yes, I am a newbie. I went from not knowing what PHP was last week, to creating an API integration for a new device we created. (which works perfectly by the way) and decoding the API's JSON script and searching for a value to trigger a response. I am still stumped on Webhooks though. All web references direct you to paid webhook sites that look after them for you. I really want to build my own. I have placed it onto www.p*****e.com.au/hook/hook.php